# Safe string copy in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, string

I wrote this string copy routine for C strings. It is supposed to behave like strlcpy, that is - null terminate the destination if size > 0, and return the length of the source string.

However I also want the function to fail if either the source or destination pointer is null, and somehow notify this to the caller. But I can not think of a very elegant way to do this. Right now I send two negative values as size to denote that the source or the destination pointer points to null. Hence I changed the return type from size_t to a signed integer, and I am not happy with this interface. What would be a better interface?

```
  #include <cstddef> // size_t
  #include <cstdint> // 32 bit int

  const std::int32_t SRC_NULL = -1;
  const std::int32_t DST_NULL = -2;

  std::int32_t CopyStringn (char *dest, const char *src, std::size_t size) {
     const char* temp (src);
     if (temp == NULL)
         return SRC_NULL;
     if (dest == NULL)
         return DST_NULL;
     while (*temp) {
        if (size > 1) {
           *dest++ = *temp;
           --size;
        }
        ++temp;
     }

     if (size)
         *dest = '\0';

     return static_cast<std::int32_t> (temp - src); // Length does not include null
}
```

Comment: If you're using C++, is there any particular reason you *aren't* using `std::string`?

Comment: If you want a magic value to indicate null inputs, what about 0? Then return source string length *including* the null rather than excluding it, so it's always at least 1 in all other cases. Two magic values seems like overkill - do callers really need to use this function to check which of two pointers is null? If there's a genuine need for such a function, couldn't it be separated from this function, which is about copying strings.

Comment: @dreamlax Ohh.. I am using / modifying some code which uses a lot of c style coding, and also strcpy and strtok, and hence silently fails sometimes :( So I was removing these functions with relatively safer ones.

Comment: It would probably be easier to replace with `std::string`, and less error-prone.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In C++, you can throw an exception.

Answer (score 1):

Magic return values are rarely a good idea. I expect such a function to tell me how many chars would be copied, and that is what should be returned. If src or dest is NULL, you copy 0 characters, return 0.

Alternatively, you can choose to return either 1/true if everything was copied and properly 0-terminated, and 0/false otherwise.

Comment: size will not become zero, as size only decreases it size > 1.

Comment: You're right, don't know why my brain insisted that said `size >= 1`. Edited.

Comment: "I expect such a function to tell me how many chars were copied" - that's not what `strlcpy` returns, though, so might not be what the target audience of this function expects.

Comment: Ok it's really getting late here (3am) I'll change "were" to "would be" and go to bed :P